# No module named 'transformers.models.t5.modeling_t5'

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, anaconda, huggingface-transformers

I am building an ML model using torch, huggingface transformers and t5 in Jupyter Notebook. When I try to run the following import command

```
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.t5.modeling_t5'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-fe19be9f8ddf> in <module>
      1 from transformers import T5Tokenizer
      2 from transformers import AdamW
----> 3 from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration
      4 from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in __getattr__(self, name)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in __getattr__(self, name)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.t5.modeling_t5 because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'transformers.models.t5.modeling_t5'
```

The versions I have used in imports are as follow

```
!pip install transformers==2.9.0
!pip uninstall tokenizers --yes
!pip install tokenizers
!pip install --ignore-installed PyYAML
!pip install pytorch_lightning==0.7.5
!pip install torch==1.4.0
```

The module I'm trying to install is here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/t5/modeling_t5.py . Why is it giving me this particular issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: You will need a higher version of `transformers` and `pytorch`, try this combo `pip install -U transformers>=4.26.1 pytorch>=1.13.1 tokenizers>0.13.2`

Comment: @alvas if I use a higher version of transformers, tokenizers are not available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are using Python 3.10 as a kernel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).